# Typescript errors in external npm dependencies

Tags: typescript

I have a `tsconfig.json` file which excludes:

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "**/*-test.ts",
  "typings/*",
  "**/*.d.ts"
]
```

And yet in my attempts to transpile and lint I get the following error:

> node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.d.ts(166,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

Does this make sense? I thought any errors within external dependencies should be excluded based on the above exclude.

p.s. the code -- including 3rd party deps -- works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exclude` part tells the compiler which files/folders not to compile, but if a file that is being compiled is using a file in that is in the excluded list it will still be compiled, or as it states [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details):

> Any files that are referenced by files included via the "files" or
>   "include" properties are also included. Similarly, if a file B.ts is
>   referenced by another file A.ts, then B.ts cannot be excluded unless
>   the referencing file A.ts is also specified in the "exclude" list.

If you are using a library that uses `Promise` then you better target `es6` which should make this error disappear, but if you prefer not to then you can use the [`--skipLibCheck` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) which:

> Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts)

---

#### Edit

In the [aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) github readme file, in the [Usage with TypeScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js#usage-with-typescript) section under [Pre-requisites](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js#pre-requisites) it clearly states:

> Your tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json includes 'dom' and
>   'es2015.promise' under compilerOptions.lib

Comment: I am targeting Node 4.x so I can't go to **es6** but shouldn't an external party as popular as AWS resolve WRT to promises by itself? Also for what it's worth I'm using Bluebird for promises in my code ... although maybe not in all modules which reference this dependency. Shouldn't Bluebird provide the definition for a 3rd party library using "Promise"?

Comment: The aws library isn't aware that you're using bluebird so it doesn't import it (my guess) which is why it isn't available for it.

Comment: yeah that part makes sense but if I am importing Bluebird _and_ AWS (and Bluebird does define "Promise") then shouldn't this error be avoided? I have no confirmed that any cases where I import `aws-sdk`, I also import `import * as Promise from 'bluebird'`.

Comment: Importing bluebird in **your** modules doesn't make it available in other modules you're importing. For example, maybe the aws library is actually using bluebird itself but a different version than yours? Maybe it uses another promise library.

Comment: ok that was originally what I'd presumed but then it is misbehaving, right? It is _assuming_ but not defining a Promise definition.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following code to tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
          "es5",
          "es2015.promise"
        ]
      }
```